# Is there a way of getting summary and polyline information in the same Here REST API V8 Routes response?

Tags: rest, here-api

I need summary information for length between waypoints and also the polylines of each section. The "return" parameter appears to gives me only one option (summary) or another (polyline). I want to achieve this by only one request to the Rounting API v8. Would be it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine multiple **return** parameters. The parameter to provide information about maneuvers is **actions** (or **turnByTurnActions**). In your case:

`return=summary,polyline,actions`

---

Below is full routing request taken from [HERE Maps for JavaScript API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/services/map-with-route-from-a-to-b) example:

https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY&routingMode=fast&transportMode=car&origin=52.5160%2C13.3779&destination=52.5206%2C13.3862&return=polyline%2Cactions%2CtravelSummary%2Ctinstructions

Response example:

```
routes": [
  {
    "id": "ccaa74a9-d866-465b-ac8c-2846cfeaaff0",
    "sections": [
      {
        "id": "dffa50af-9e71-4585-b504-fdcd808d098e",
        "type": "vehicle",
        "actions": [
          {
            "action": "depart",
            "duration": 32,
            "length": 85,
            "instruction": "Head southeast on Pariser Platz. Go for 85 m.",
            "offset": 0
          },
          ...
```